# Facebook directory application advice

Tags: facebook

I'm a complete newbie about Facebook applications, and need some advice on whether the following application is feasible:

The application would essentially enable users to choose a photo from their album, which would be displayed in the application's "directory" alongside their name and age. If possible, their photo would link to their Facebook profile. Application users can browse the listed users. It would be aimed at performers; hence the directory.

Would this be possible; if so, what would be the best way to approach it?
Furthermore, does the app violate any Facebook terms of service regarding data if the user has given permissions? And how does storing user emails work if they have given email access?

I know there are several questions, so any help would be appreciated! I will not be making the application myself, but would like to know how it could be done so I have a clear understanding when talking to programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is definitely possible to implement your application. Your questions are very vague - If you could be more specific, I'd try to answer them for you. When the user initially logs into your application, it will have to pass to Facebook the list of permissions your application requires. Once the user okays it, your application will have access to all the data it has requested.